# extension in google protocol buffer leading to abort

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, abort

My problem with original protocol message class, it is running fine.

```
message StrategyMessage {
  required bytes name = 1;
  optional int64 timestamp = 3;
  extensions 33 to 63;

}

extend StrategyMessage {
    /// many optional fields

    optional int64 best_bid=39;
}
```

And whenever I use extended fields below pasted gives me the errors.

```
strategy_message_.SetExtension(utils::strategy_controller::best_bid,best_bid_);
LOG_DEBUG(logger_, " Sending message to U/I \n");
if (!strategy_controller_client_->send_message(strategy_message_)) {
            LOG_DEBUG(logger_, "ERROR: couldn't send message to U/I\n");
}
```

This gives error.

```
10/03/16 17:48:07.593132144 D  Sending message to U/I 

libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/message_lite.cc:270] CHECK failed: (end) == (reinterpret_cast<uint8*>(data) + byte_size): 

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
[Switching to Thread 0x7fffd8de8700 (LWP 63533)]
0x00007ffff4ef25d7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

but when I run it after changing it as shown below, it worked.

```
strategy_message_.set_timestamp(timestamp);
LOG_DEBUG(logger_, " Sending message to U/I \n");
if (!strategy_controller_client_->send_message(strategy_message_)) {
            LOG_DEBUG(logger_, "ERROR: couldn't send message to U/I\n");
}
```

The send_message() is implemented as shown below.

```
bool StrategyControllerClient::send_message(StrategyMessage& msg) {
  if (server_side_fd_ < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  msg.set_server_ip(local_interface_ip_);
  return send_message_impl(msg, server_side_fd_);
}

bool StrategyControllerClient::send_message_impl(const ::google::protobuf::Message& msg, int fd) {
  uint32_t size = msg.ByteSize();
  if (size > nMaxSizeOfMessageToServer) {
    ERROR_LOG << ::utils::current_time_ns() << " Msg to Server is too big: " << size << "\n";
    ERROR_LOG << msg.DebugString() << "\n";
    return false;
  }
  message_allocator_lock_.lock();
  MessageToServer* tm = message_allocator_->allocate();
  message_allocator_lock_.unlock();
  tm->msg.fd_identifier = fd;
  tm->msg.data_iov[0].iov_len = size;
  msg.SerializeToArray(tm->msg.data_iov[0].iov_base, size);
  if (!network_io_manager_->send_msg(&tm->msg)) {  // We won't get a callback so deallocate
    ERROR_LOG << ::utils::current_time_ns() << " Error in sending message to Server(2)\n";
    ERROR_LOG << msg.DebugString() << "\n";
    message_allocator_lock_.lock();
    message_allocator_->deallocate(tm);
    message_allocator_lock_.unlock();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

**EDIT:** The program is having no leaks.

```
==68909== LEAK SUMMARY:
==68909==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68909==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68909==      possibly lost: 19,778 bytes in 404 blocks
==68909==    still reachable: 280,616 bytes in 964 blocks
==68909==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==68909== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==68909== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==68909== 
==68909== ERROR SUMMARY: 322 errors from 322 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

**EDIT2:** The program is aborting in the line.

```
msg.SerializeToArray(tm->msg.data_iov[0].iov_base, size);
```

Comment: You may have a memory corruption somewhere. Check your application with `valgrind` first.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, updated the results

Comment: Are you saying that your application does not crash under `valgrind`?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, its seems no abort is called this time.

Comment: If it crashes without `valgrind` but not with it, that probably means there is a race condition. `valgrind` simulates only one thread at a time, so you may not observe race conditions resulting from threads executing simultaneously.

Comment: I think @MaximEgorushkin is right that this is likely a race condition. This error suggests that the message might have been modified in another thread while it was being serialized.